# Store Arrays as Hash?

Tags: ruby

I'm pulling CSV data then storing it as arrays.  I need to return these arrays as a single Hash.

This will allow me to use a key for each index, instead of using the index number, but I'm having issues getting it to work. It logs an error saying there is the wrong number of arguments.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Code:

```
ref       = Array.new
summary   = Array.new
pri       = Array.new
state     = Array.new
estdur    = Array.new
notes     = Array.new
supporter = Array.new
bz        = Array.new
project   = Array.new
team      = Array.new

hashed = Hash.new

csvPath = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}"+"/../modules/csv.csv"
CSV.foreach(csvPath, :headers=>true, :header_converters=>:symbol) do |row|
  ref       << row [ :feature   ]
  summary   << row [ :Summary   ]
  pri       << row [ :Pri       ]
  state     << row [ :State     ]
  estdur    << row [ :EstDur    ]
  notes     << row [ :Notes     ]
  supporter << row [ :Supporter ]
  bz        << row [ :BZ        ]
  project   << row [ :Project   ]
  team      << row [ :Team      ]
end
return hashed[
  "ref",       ref,
  "summary",   summary,
  "pri",       pri,
  "state",     state,
  "estDur",    estdur,
  "notes",     notes,
  "supporter", supporter,
  "bz",        bz,
  "project",   project,
  "team",      team
]
```

Comment: Post the exact error with stack trace. And point out which line is causing the error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev error is on the return at the end, and as stated above, it say's wrong number of arguments (20 for 1)

Comment: Instead of `Hash.new` you can use `{ }` just like JavaScript. `Array.new` is equivalent to `[ ]`.

Comment: As as note you can declare your array vars like this  `ref, summary, pri, state, estdur, notes, supporter, bz, project, team = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []` It's a lot less wordy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you're going about this is rather confused. Any time you see a large number of variables like that is a sign you should be using a different storage method. That you collapse these into a Hash before returning them is a hint as to how they should be stored in the first place.

Here's a re-working that's much more Ruby flavored:

```
# Create a Hash where the default is an empty Array
result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }

# Create a mapping table that defaults to the downcase version of the key
mapping = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = k.to_s.downcase.to_sym }

# Over-ride certain keys that don't follow the default mapping
mapping[:feature] = :ref

csvPath = File.expand_path("/../modules/csv.csv", File.dirname(__FILE__))

CSV.foreach(csvPath, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
  row.each do |column, value|
    # Append values to the array under the re-mapped key
    result[mapping[column]] << value
  end
end

# Return the resulting hash
result
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to launch into code-review mode but you beat me to it.

Comment: @tadman I agree that's a lot cleaner, I seem to be getting nill as the return value, even though if I use it as a plain array of arrays, it works just fine. Any suggestions why that may be?

Comment: Make sure `result` is the last line of your method.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
return Hash["ref", ref, "summary", summary, "pri", pri, "state", state, 
            "estDur", estdur, "notes", notes, "supporter", supporter, 
            "bz", bz, "project", project, "team", team]
```

No need for `hashed` variable.

Comment: No need for a `return` either if it's the last line of the method.

Comment: @Matzi, the arrays else where return nil values, although I'm quite certain the information is being read as with using arrays instead of hash it gives the correct data?